# Facebook Login button doesn't change to logout after login Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, facebook, cordova

Im developing an android application in Phonegap.
I m trying to connect to facebook
I have a login button , when i click on it i connect to facebook , i accept the permissions and i return to the application.
when i return , i saw a login button and a logout button , after a few time , the login button disappear and there is only a logout button in the place of the login button.

My problem is that i show a login and a logout button both of them for a few minute when i return to my app after a login. i want to login to facebook and when i return to the application the login button hide and the logout button show.

Here is my HTML Code login and logout button and facebook init.

```
 <div class="section">
   <div class="show_when_not_connected">
     <div id="login_button" class="autorization_btn"><a onclick="promptLogin();" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="icon-facebook"></i>Login</a></div>                               
     </div>
   <div class="show_when_connected">
     <div id="login_button" class=" autorization_btn" ><a onclick="logout();" class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm"> Logout</a></div>                                  
     </div>
```

```
<script>

  // Initialize the Facebook SDK
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() 
  {
      FB.init
      ({
          appId: 'fbId',
          nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
          useCachedDialogs: false
      });       

      FB.getLoginStatus(handleStatusChange);        
      authUser();
      updateAuthElements();
  });
```

Here is my js code , that let me Handle status changes:

```
function handleStatusChange(session) 
{
console.log('Got the user\'s session: ' + JSON.stringify(session));
alert('Got the user\'s session: ' + JSON.stringify(session));

if (session.authResponse) 
{
    //document.body.className = 'connected';

    //Fetch user's id, name, and picture
    FB.api('/me', 
    {
      fields: 'name, picture,first_name,last_name,email'
    },
    function(response) 
    {
      if (!response.error) 
      {
        document.body.className = 'connected';

        user = response;

        console.log('Got the user\'s name and picture: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
        console.log('FB name, ' + response.name);


        //Update display of user name and picture
        if (document.getElementById('user-name')) 
        {
          document.getElementById('user-name').innerHTML = user.name;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('user-picture')) 
        {
          document.getElementById('user-picture').src = user.picture.data.url;
        }

      }
      else 
      {
        document.body.className = 'not_connected';
        console.log('Error getting user info: ' + JSON.stringify(response.error));

        if (response.error.error_subcode && response.error.error_subcode == "458") 
        {
          setTimeout(function() 
                  {
            alert("The app was removed. Please log in again.");
          }, 0);              
        }
        logout();         
      }

      clearAction();
    });
}
else  {
  document.body.className = 'not_connected';

  clearAction();
}   

}

 function authUser() 
  {
   FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', handleStatusChange);
  }
```

PS : When i login to facebook and return i show two buttons login and logout for few time, after that i have this alert "alert('Got the user\'s session: ' + JSON.stringify(session));" , after this alert the login button disapear and i have only a logout button.

Here is the CSS code that let me Hide and show the login and logout button

```
 .section 
  {
   float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e9e9e9;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  }


  body.connected .show_when_not_connected 
  {
    display: none;
  }

  body.connected .show_when_connected
  {
     display: block;
  }

  body.not_connected .show_when_not_connected 
 {
   display: block;
 }

 body.not_connected .show_when_connected 
 {
  display: none;
 }
```

Is it better to work with  in phonegap, is there a possibility to show and hide login and logout button
Is there an exemple on how to use it expect the facebook documentation.

Thanks a lot for your help